# javascript selected options function not working in IE and safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Any help on this would be MUCH appreciated!

I am having a problem with this javascript code in IE and Safari only.

It works fine in other browser e.g firefox and chrome.

I believe in IE and Safari it's not cycling through all the select option values correctly. e.g. in firefox there are two values for p, however in safari only 1 value.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selected(val, val1)
{
    var len = document.getElementById('attribute122').length;
    var p;
    for(p=0;p<len;p++)
    {
        if(document.getElementById('attribute122')[p].label == val1)
        {
            document.getElementById('attribute122').value = document.getElementById('attribute122')[p].value;
            document.getElementById('att_'+val).className = 'active';
        }
        else
        {
            if(document.getElementById('attribute122')[p].label !="Choose an Option...")
            {
                var chalpeveere = document.getElementById('attribute122')[p].label;
                // alert(chalpeveere);
                chalpeveere = chalpeveere.replace('.','_');
                // alert(chalpeveere);
                document.getElementById('att_' + chalpeveere).className = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-box">
<select id="attribute122" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" name="super_attribute[122]">
<option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
<option value="3" price="0">Medium</option>
</select>
</div>


<div class="Medium">
<a id="att_Medium" class="none" href="javascript:selected('Medium', 'Medium')"> </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments:

```
function selected(val, val1) {
    var len = document.getElementById('attribute122').length;
```

Much better to store a reference to the element. If it's a select element, its length is the number of options. It's clearer to write it that way:

```
    var select = document.getElementById('attribute122');
    var len = select.options.length;
```

But I wouldn't set `len` here, see below.

It's much more common to use `i`, `j`, `k`, etc. as loop counters and to initialise them in the for expression. It's common to set the limit here too:

```
    for (var i=0, len=select.options.length; i<len; i++) {

      if (select[p].label == val1) {
```

Again, while you can access the options as properties of the select element, it's clearer to access them via the options collection. Also, the `label` property is more commonly known as `text`, so:

```
      if (select.options[i].text == val1) {
```

.

```
        document.getElementById('attribute122').value = document.getElementById('attribute122')[p].value;
```

Setting the selected option by setting the value of the select element is also very new behaviour, it is far more common to set the option to selected:

```
        select.selectedIndex = i;
```

or

```
        select.options[i].selected = true;
```

.

```
        document.getElementById('att_'+val).className = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
        if(document.getElementById('attribute122')[p].label !="Choose an Option...")
        {
```

Pesumably that is the first option, so you can just test:

```
        if (select.selectedIndex != 0) {
```

.

```
            var chalpeveere = document.getElementById('attribute122')[p].label;
```

becomes:

```
            var chalpeveere = select.optoins[i].text;
```

.

```
            // alert(chalpeveere);
            chalpeveere = chalpeveere.replace('.','_');
            // alert(chalpeveere);
            document.getElementById('att_' + chalpeveere).className = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So the tidied code becomes:

```
function selected(val, val1) {
    var select = document.getElementById('attribute122'); 
    var options = select.options;

    for(var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {

        if (options[i].text == val1) {
            options[i].selected = true;
            document.getElementById('att_'+val).className = 'active';

        } else {

            if (select.selectedIndex != 0) {
                var chalpeveere = options[i].text;
                // alert(chalpeveere);
                chalpeveere = chalpeveere.replace('.','_');
                // alert(chalpeveere);
                document.getElementById('att_' + chalpeveere).className = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<a id="att_Medium" class="none" href="javascript:selected('Medium', 'Medium')">foo</a>
```

If you want a button, use a button:

```
<button id="att_Medium" class="none" onclick="
  selected('Medium', 'Medium')
">Set selected</button>
```

or use a style span.

Comment: slightly modified version of your code fixed the issue. thanks so much!